can I set letter-spacing globally for an angular material project
Disclaimer: I'm not very good with Angular at all but am tasked with maintaining a leftover project.
After an update from angular 13 to angular 18 (with the big hump being 14>15), I find a lot of my letter spacing broken and so I'm wasting my time finding out the correct variables through the developer tools and inspect (is this even the right way), and then overwriting them in my styles.scss like so:
html {
    --mdc-list-list-item-label-text-tracking: normal;
    --mdc-text-button-label-text-tracking: normal;
    --mat-legacy-button-toggle-selected-state-text-color: black;
    --mdc-list-list-item-focus-state-layer-color: none;
    --mdc-filled-text-field-label-text-tracking: normal;
}

As you can see the text-tracking (i.e. letter-spacing) is always too wide for my liking and I want it down to normal. Do I have to do this for every component or can I set a global letter-spacing?

Your issue is that Angular Material has updated their configuration between the major 14/15
You need to provide the font now.
You should have some style like this :
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The "warn" palette is optional and defaults to red if not specified.
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
   warn: $my-warn,
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(), // <--- THIS LINE IS REQUIRED NOW
 density: 0,
));


I have that. But how does that set my letter-spacing though.

I had the same problem. You do have to add mat.define-typography-config() to your theme, but there's a little more to it. If all you do is pass the empty config, it will set everything up with defaults and in the case of letter spacing, "normal" may not be what you want.
If you look here:
https://angular-material.dev/courses/m2-ng-components/m2-ng-components/modify-typography
There is a walkthrough of handling typography. What worked for me was portion under the subheader "create config." In order to get our monorepo (Angular 16) to take the settings, I set up each of the typography levels to look like this:
$custom-font-family: '"Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif';
$typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: $custom-font-family,
  $headline-1: mat.define-typography-level(
    $font-size: 36px,
    $letter-spacing: 0,
    $font-weight: 300,
  ),
  $headline-2: mat.define-typography-level(
    $font-size: 32px,
    $letter-spacing: 0,
    $font-weight: 400,
  ), // and so on for the rest of the typography settings

The thing to note here is the use of variable declarations such as $font-size and $letter-spacing. Until I used that specific syntax, nothing I did worked. To be clear, this is the only part of the linked article I used and that worked for my specific need (apply letter-spacing globally across an Angular monorepo). Perhaps other parts of that documentation will be useful for you as well.
The documentation says you don't have to pass in all of the variables. Just the ones you want to change. So if you're happy with default font-weight, you don't have to add it to the config. Since we have written style guidelines that define all of the typography settings, I set the theme up with our specific rules.
Hopefully this help you. Good luck!
